# What is this warning with Web links in Play Console?

Tags: android, deep-linking, google-play-console, android-deep-link

I got this warning in `Play Console > Deep links > Web links` like the screenshot below. Why I have checkmark "`All deep links working`" but I got this warning "`Non-redirect URL failed`
"
Any idea how to resolve it? thanks

[image]